# Internal error: [CoreUtil/General]: index too large

Tags: iar

How to fix the above error ? I am trying to build my code on IAR embedded workbench through makefile. While building, it throws the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I think more details need to be specified. If you can paste the full error you got when compiling the code, that will help. Also compiling error must be referring to some source file with a specified line number also....It will be helpful if you can paste the snippet around the line of error from the source file.

Comment: This is not an answer. You should post this as a comment to the question.